# how to replace content of a PDF files either paragraph wise or sentence wise in java.

Tags: java, pdf

I have one PDF file. I want to replace few paragraphs of this PDF file by some other text from files like(.doc/ .docx/ .xls). how to scan and edit text paragraph wise or sentence wise in the same PDF document.

Thanks alot in advance..

Comment: Try apache pdfbox or itext library.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that if you modify text in a PDF it will somehow be seamlessly integrated into the document.  The PDF is like a printed page that has already been laid out.  Decisions about page layout (where a text box is, for instance) were made by the program that originally wrote the PDF.  While you can make small changes using PDFBox or iText, don't expect the page format and text flow to magically adjust to the new text.  A PDF is like a printed page. You could apply some white-out or cut/paste some paper corrections, but the layout won't adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDFBox library (http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to extract the text from PDF and use hssf library to extract the data from word or excel file. Then you can do all your manipulations and finally create new PDF doc with the updated text data.

Comment: That *might* work as easily as you make it sound if replacements use roughly the same space as the original. But if not, we are talking about re-flowing the whole document. In case of irregular columns, images embedded into paragraphs, annotations applied to text sequences, page decorations, ... It is all but easy.

Comment: fetching data through HSSF/ apache POI is fine. But replacing text from PDF through iText or PDF Box api is not possible. Any other idea is highly appreciable.

Comment: Let's answer your question with a question. I give you a printed page. And I ask you to insert this long paragraph in place of the two words I highlighted. All you have in your hand is the paper. How are you going to make it happen?